# How do I check for internet connection OSX

Tags: macos, applescript, wifi

My iMac wi-fi is a bit unstable. Sometimes it says it's connected and has full signal, but webpages won't load in Safari or Chrome. I have to turn wifi off/on to fix it.

The weird thing is when I ping google.com on Terminal, I have 0% packet loss.

```
PING www.google.com (68.104.213.123):
56 data bytes 64 bytes from 68.104.213.123: icmp_seq=0 ttl=52 time=21.530 ms

--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 21.530/21.530/21.530/0.000 ms
```

I made this Apple Script to try to fix this, but it seems like I need another method for checking actual internet connection instead of just pinging. What could I do?

```
repeat
    try
        do shell script "ping -o -t 2 www.google.com"
    on error
        say "Couldn't connect"
        do shell script "networksetup -setairportpower en1 off"
        do shell script "sleep 5"
        do shell script "networksetup -setairportpower en1 on"
    end try
    delay 60
end repeat
```

Comment: are you saying that you can ping google in terminal but cannot display the google web page in safari ?

Comment: yes, i can ping google in terminal, but nothing else works, Safari, Chrome, etc...

Comment: This is what I get in Terminal: 
`PING www.google.com (68.104.213.123): 56 data bytes`
`64 bytes from 68.104.213.123: icmp_seq=0 ttl=52 time=21.530 ms`
`--- www.google.com ping statistics ---`
`1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0.0% packet loss`
`round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 21.530/21.530/21.530/0.000 ms`

Comment: It could be your wifi antenna is becoming flakey. Large bandwidth requests (like almost everything on the web these days) require good hardware. A failing wifi antenna plaqued my iphone (too many drops I guess). It had similar symptoms- email worked on LTE but not wifi. Do you have an external wifi adapter you can try(like a cheap usb wifi stick)? Does the problem occur with a wired connection?

Comment: You're right, that probably is the problem. ill look into it. In the meantime, do you know of a way to adjust my script so that it checks for an internet connection?

Comment: try using 'curl www.apple.com'

Comment: I have exactly same problem as yours. Thanks for your script. :)

Answer (score 2):

`curl www.apple.com` will access the internet from terminal

Comment: This worked for me, thank you! I replaced the 3rd line with `do shell script "curl --max-time 4 www.google.com"`

Comment: isn't there a connectivity check in place by macOS itself, so that the state of the connection could be requested from the network-adapter itself directly without having to make another connection access? I was hoping `networkservice` could help here, without success. Btw, curling `apple.com` seems to be the better choice, as macOS will connect to Apple anyways. Not so much for Google.

Answer (score 0):

Get inspiration from above question and answer, I changed code as below:

```
on idle
    try
        do shell script "curl -m 4 www.google.com"
    on error
        say "Couldn't connect"
        do shell script "networksetup -setairportpower en1 off"
        do shell script "sleep 5"
        do shell script "networksetup -setairportpower en1 on"
    end try
    return 60
end idle
```

Because if you use `repeat`, you cannot exit program. By using `on idle`, you can easily exit program at any time. But you MUST save the script as runnable and check the keep it running checkbox when saving.